# Python Child Class Instance is Unable to Access Parent Initiated Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

Here is the background. I am making a game in python 3.7 using the Pyglet library. I am trying to access just a boolean variable called `dead` that is initiated in the parent class's `__init__` function. In the child class, I have called the parent's `__init__` function within the child's own `__init__`. Whenever I try to access `dead` variable from the parent methods inherited by the child class, I keep getting an error that the child class cannot find the variable.

Parent class is called PhysicalObject within physicalobject.py:

```
import pyglet

class PhysicalObject(pyglet.prite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dead = False
```

Child class is called Player within player.py (same directory as physicalobject.py. Directory is called `game`)

```
import pyglet
from game import physicalobject

class Player(physialobject.PhysicalObject):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.dead)
```

Finally from the main script file one directory level up, we bring it all together and create the player:

```
import pyglet
from game import player

p = player.Player()
```

I'm not sure why the child cannot see `self.dead` on the last line here `print(self.dead)`, but I know I am not understanding something right about inheritance. I am not used to python, but in other programming languages we define our variables first before `__init__` and I know doing so in python will result in a static variable, but that seems to be the only way that I can get the result I am looking for. I have been searching for hours trying to get this to work going through every suggestion already asked on stack overflow with no luck.

Exact error below:

`AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'dead'`

EDIT: This was never technically answered, but when trying to do the exact same thing as bare bones as I could make it, I got that barebones script to work using the same styled syntax as above. I need to break down my project further to figure out exactly what is happening, but when I find out, I will be back to revise this post again.

Comment: Firstly, please fix your indentation. Secondly, state *exactly* what happens when you print the variable. What error do you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, added the error at the bottom. Also fixed the indents.

Comment: This code should work fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The beauty of it is it doesn't. When I get home in the morning I'm about to post the whole zip file of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyglet
from game import physicalobject

class Player(physialobject.PhysicalObject):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    PhysicalObject.__init__(self)
    print(self.dead)
```

This solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyglet

class PhysicalObject(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.dead = False

class Player(PhysicalObject):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(self.dead)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  p = Player()
```

It works, Try to import the `PhysicalObject` class properly.

Comment: I revised my response a bit for you because I actually create the player from a main running script file while the 2 classes are defined outside of the main script file in their own files.

Comment: import other classes in the main script file from respective file paths. did you try that?

Comment: Just for fun, I just moved the player class at the bottom of the physicalobject.py file to see if it would work for that, but unfortunately even without having to import the class from another file, it still couldn't find the variable. Same error